# What's the meaning of the word 'bias' in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

**Here's the context:**

> This assumes that when a pair particle-antiparticle is created, a **bias** towards antiparticles being captured and particles escaping must exist.
>
> Otherwise, the mass of the black hole might fluctuate, but in average for big numbers of pairs, equal percentage of particles and antiparticles would be captured/escape.
>
> So, is there really a **bias** needed for the black hole to loose mass, or is it something wrong about my understanding of Hawking radiation?

What is a bias in this context?
Could you give me examples of expressions using the word 'bias'?
My interpretation of this text is that a particle or an anti-particle do some sort of wrong action towards each other that should not be acceptable, but that doesn't make much sense because they are not persons nor they have capacity to judge. So what am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. What did you find in the dictionary when you looked up “bias”, and why didn’t that help?

Comment: I found that bias is a prejudice against someone in an unfair way, although it doesn't make sense to me in this context

Comment: I think it would help if you would  [edit] to add that information into your question. If you explain a little bit about what you think about that passage and why it’s difficult to understand, it will help us to write better answers.

Answer (score 1):

"Bias" has a few different, but sort-of related, definitions. I think the one that applies best to your context is given by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bias) as definition d(1):

> "deviation of the expected value of a statistical estimate from the
>   quantity it estimates"